# Standalone Qt Designer installation

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, raspberry-pi

I develop applications with Netbeans on my Windows PC for the Raspberry Pi and build them remotely on the Raspberry Pi. Now I also would like to develop some GUIs with Qt. Because of remote building I need **neither MinGW nor Qt modules** (RPi of course has everything necessary installed), *only Qt Designer* to edit the Qt Forms.

How can I install Qt Designer only or at least with as little additional stuff as possible?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to download a Qt binary, unzip it, then remove the parts used for compiling user code - i.e. leave only the `bin`, `plugins`, `resources` and `translation` folders. You can further pare down what's in the `bin` and `translation` folders.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt standalone installer binary built with Qt installer framework which accepts scripts also, you can write scripts and customize which you want to install with those scripts, look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279733/4490542 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032216/4490542

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else ending up here. Here is a standalone installer someone made:
https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

Comment: Is this "someone" trustable?